# Base64 pdf data Uri is not working in IE9 & IE10

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In IE9 and IE10 also, Base64 data Uri is not working in the object tag to load the pdf. It is showing a message below "Access Denied".

```
<object id="objPdf" data="data:application/pdf;charset=utf-8;base64,{myValue}" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

[image]

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 2):

IE doesn't support the data protocol. Per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the only supported elements/attributes are the following:

```
object (images only)
img
input type=image
link
CSS declarations that accept a URL, such as background, backgroundImage, and so on.
```

Besides, there's also a "IE 10 treats blob URL as cross-origin and denies access" bug filled against IE, still open and active.

I just ran into the same issue when trying to serve CSV data (`data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,...`)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but if someone comes across this on a Google search the solution is that you need to have a URL or API endpoint that will return your pdf data, then you put the address to that in your object's data attribute.

```
<object data="/api/pdf"
```

If your pdf is generated by information on the page then you can send that info to the API endpoint in the querystring.